# How to validate combo box (From smaller value to bigger value)

Tags: c#, combobox

I know sounds stupid but sry I have to ask.

How to compare the string between two **combo box** in C#?

Actually what I am looking for I would like to do the **validation** for two **combo box**.

The value of the **combo box** is **customer name**.

I would like to validate if customer **To** is (lexically) smaller than customer **From** - in other words, if **To** appears before **From** in an alphabetical ordering.

For example:

```
(customer From): ZIF        (customer To): AIH

If(cboFrom.selectedvalue > cboTo.selectedvalue)
{
}
```

red line is appear below the code
Anyone please help as I cound not found in google.
Thanks advance

Comment: So all you want to compare is the selected value in each?

Comment: What does it mean 'a string i smaller than another'? Anyway please put some code so we can get your intentions right.

Comment: you can have various events for it,use selection_change or validation.

Comment: OP, you're either trying to compare the length of the string, or the alphabetical order. I'm assuming 'smaller' you mean length, but it's too much of an assumption to propose on answer with. Also, when should the error be shown?

Comment: @DeeMac Oh yeah, should be alphabetical order. Thanks for finally got someone understand my problem. when user submit the selection with customer From Z to customer To A, error message should be shown

Comment: Can you provide some additional context? Is this a WPF or Forms application? Is it a web-page? That will also determine what kind of answers you receive.

Comment: Sry, I am using Win Form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `>` to compare strings (it won't even compile), also it makes no sense - does `>` mean longer? higher in the alphabet? if so which alphabet?

How about using [`String.Compare`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-compare)?

```
String.Compare("alpha", "beta") // returns -1
String.Compare("beta", "alpha") // returns 1
String.Compare("alpha", "alpha") // returns 0
```